# Why does image upload fail php's is_uploaded_file check?

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

I have a html form that allows image uploads, but the image uploaded now fails the "is_uploaded_file" check for some reason.

**So why does the upload fail the is_uploaded_file check?**

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="RecipeAddForm" method="post"
action="/recipes/add" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <!--- Omitted Markup -->
    <input type="file" name="data[Recipe][image]" value="" id="RecipeImage" />
    <!--- Omitted Markup -->
</form>
```

PHP:

```
// returns false
echo is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])?'true':'false';
```

I did a dump on the $file or $_FILES array:

```
Array
(
    [name] => add or remove.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => E:\\xampp\\tmp\\phpB9CB.tmp
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 71869
)
```

File size is not too large, and the error was 0. So why does it fail the is_uploaded_file check?

Comment: Might be a problem with windows, since it's case sensitive and will not match if the path is different. Try using `realpath($file['tmp_name'])`

Comment: @yoda that worked! awesome thanks! Do you want to repost that as an answer so I can select it as correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be a problem with windows, since it's case sensitive and will not match if the path is different. Try using `realpath($file['tmp_name'])`

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['data[Recipe][image]']['tmp_name']))
```

remember `$_FILES` is reserve PHP superglobal variable ..so always write in capital

u can retrieve the correct path of file using

`$filename = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);`

**NOTE:**  why u using array in the name attribute ( *name="data[Recipe][image]"*   ) ?

if there is no specific reason then alwayz make simple code

```
<input type="file" name="RecipeImage" value="" id="RecipeImage" />
```

and check simply

```
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['RecipeImage']['tmp_name']))
```

Remember [**KISS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Comment: read on `php.net` [reference](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 1):

After you have used the uploaded image (move_uploaded_file) the function is_uploaded_file always returns false.