# function is_uploaded_file( ) not working .. always returns a false flag

Tags: php, file-upload

I am uploading a file through PHP scipt ..

my code is

```
$file_temp=$_FILES["upl"]["tmp_name"];
```

when i upload stuffs with

```
move_upload_file($file_temp,"user_stuff/".$file_name)
```

Everything works fine .. stuff get uploaded with no disaster

But when i check the uploaded file to be actually in the area using

```
is_uploaded_file($file_temp);
```

It always return false

So i googled the problem and it redirected me to the same stackoverflow problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202306/why-does-image-upload-fail-phps-is-uploaded-file-check)

so i did , as it was suggested

```
 if(is_uploaded_file(realpath($file_temp)))
        {
            echo "done";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "fail";
        }
```

But still getting the same problem "fail"

Moreover, i just noticed a strange thing ... when i am not using move_uploaded_file(..) , the is_uploaded_file "works"

Comment: Have you tried `is_uploaded_file($upl);` or `is_uploaded_file($file_name);`

Comment: yes earlier, but was not working though

Answer (score 1):

try sudo chmod 777 path_to_directory/user_stuff/ -R in your console

Comment: move_upload_file($file_temp,"full path/".$file_name)

Answer (score 0):

The **`is_uploaded_file`** function returns **false** since you are checking the destination of the file which doesn't exist as you have already moved the file to a new location using `move_upload_file()`

Comment: so now should i look for is_uploaded_file($file_name), as Fred-ii- suggested , but still not working

Comment: For proper working, the function is_uploaded_file() needs an argument like $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], - the name of the uploaded file on the client's machine $_FILES['userfile']['name'] does not work.